# Basic question on the transformation of Exponential distribution.

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions

Why central moments coincide for random variables

$V\sim E(a,h)$  and $Y\sim E(h)$

where a=location parameter

h= scale parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because $E(a,h)$ is $E(h)$ translated by $a$.  Taking central moments (by subtracting the mean) removes the translation.